# Vega-Lite Binned Line Chart

Tags: vega-lite

I'm currently loving Vega-Lite but I'm running into an issue and while I've tried a lot of different things I can't seem to figure it out.

Is there a way to get the following Vega-Lite chart to have the line start and end at the edges instead of starting/ending in the middle of the bin?

```js
const data = [
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T00:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T01:00:00Z", "value": 30 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T01:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T02:00:00Z", "value": 100 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T02:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T03:00:00Z", "value": 190 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T03:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T04:00:00Z", "value": 120 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T04:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T05:00:00Z", "value": 70 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T05:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T06:00:00Z", "value": 60 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T06:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T07:00:00Z", "value": 33 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T07:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T08:00:00Z", "value": 127 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T08:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T09:00:00Z", "value": 200 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T09:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T10:00:00Z", "value": 50 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T10:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T11:00:00Z", "value": 60 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T11:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T12:00:00Z", "value": 70 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T12:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T13:00:00Z", "value": 80 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T13:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T14:00:00Z", "value": 90 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T14:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T15:00:00Z", "value": 100 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T15:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T16:00:00Z", "value": 22 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T16:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T17:00:00Z", "value": 190 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T17:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T18:00:00Z", "value": 37 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T18:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T19:00:00Z", "value": 33 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T19:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T20:00:00Z", "value": 150 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T20:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T21:00:00Z", "value": 170 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T21:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T22:00:00Z", "value": 130 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T22:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T23:00:00Z", "value": 200 },
  { "start_time": "2021-07-10T23:00:00Z", "end_time": "2021-07-10T24:00:00Z", "value": 55 }
];

const spec = {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "autosize": {
    "type": "fit",
    "resize": true,
    "contains": "content"
  },
  "height": 150,
  "width": "container",
  "data": { "values": data },
  "mark": {
    "type": "line",
    "point": true
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "start_time",
      "bin": { "binned": true },
      "type": "temporal",
      "title": "Time"
    },
    "x2": {
      "field": "end_time"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Count"
    }
  }
};

vegaEmbed('#vis', spec);
```

```css
#vis {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.20.2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5.0.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.18.2"></script>

<div id="vis"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give padding in scale of x-axis, with that you will be able to remove spacing. There are other configs like `innerPadding` which you can check in documentation. But padding seemed to work. Also noticed that by removing the `x2` encoding gave the same result of start/end connecting with edge. Refer the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQSBpjYQaALzhpQmAJ44d6AGZ1FIAE5wN2tJksM4SqHMxIasiGhCvZmOH8QAF8leBoyLDQARjEABiUAdxoAE3ofP3dPOEsLFKR3XRBiJEEnb1QAbVAId0tMAH1MGgRjEAAmOPbo-jiAdn5ouIAVOLjUMYm4gC0LQJSmlrbO7t6BodHoqanZpRKy4wBmONCausbm1p8Vnv7BkbitybHdkHnFq-QbtfvR9u2XhZ9k4YmNTiBakh6h9ll1busHv9njM5rIFpdYas7hs4ocASi9qUQahogBOE4KM5Qi5La5wn44vHI17vDF0rEI0YAFnxr2BxminXBkOhbK+9OxDx5zNR6Np4o5vziYl5QKJxj6FKpovlHQlnOVqqUrN130lowAbEbiuq0BatRDzjD2fClVaZca0c6Fa6cX1rfy0IdDsKnWK9Yq-daTZ8I76HgAOAO2kntPqh6neuMMxPRr3hs0G0nJg5oToOkU02OFpXFj1vfOm-W-IYl4nxDM66vNjat+sxzHx4bRJ7jQGE0uoe2dquDnPD0c7WVZmu9pFjgk2yeamcrnsjQV5uXdyMHpkbvkphMVsNN0-D89Lz3Hufm6LSi9qyfk3cF-fDj8nwbF8XXnWI2wFMFKUdTM-3vcD+0bE8h2id1PwnYl2naX87xQtCgIHUC339etAxJH9oMrPd4JI9DgOolCk1IlNDnTSjb2QsCmLowifTAus6LI4McM4t8BIIpDX05ToIJiDt2Ng3D5xkxCQL481ulkkkdwUrspN+TTVIY5T1yAsjomOET9I2LCj2MjTH3HLdMKg7VZyI6THM3Xjsw0wCnLIsQxGCABdUIQGQSwAGsigMIwfGEWQdCUHA2E8TB7EcOBwsCVwUk8MgigADyKMw4EEFIfCotklCYTwijq2Qksq1AHCccLoFKYxQBwJAUny2RCvQfgExCJQ4raAIEFSyxSgsZpMEENphlpcKivaUqaHKlr6LZcL9E27afEDcbDDaABHBgkH8OgChoUh5roJafAAYTYBggmCL6gA) and snipped below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "autosize": {"type": "fit", "resize": true, "contains": "content"},
  "height": 150,
  "width": "container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T00:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T01:00:00Z",
        "value": 30
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T01:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T02:00:00Z",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T02:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T03:00:00Z",
        "value": 190
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T03:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T04:00:00Z",
        "value": 120
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T04:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T05:00:00Z",
        "value": 70
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T05:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T06:00:00Z",
        "value": 60
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T06:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T07:00:00Z",
        "value": 33
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T07:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T08:00:00Z",
        "value": 127
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T08:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T09:00:00Z",
        "value": 200
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T09:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T10:00:00Z",
        "value": 50
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T10:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T11:00:00Z",
        "value": 60
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T11:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T12:00:00Z",
        "value": 70
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T12:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T13:00:00Z",
        "value": 80
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T13:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T14:00:00Z",
        "value": 90
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T14:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T15:00:00Z",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T15:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T16:00:00Z",
        "value": 22
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T16:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T17:00:00Z",
        "value": 190
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T17:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T18:00:00Z",
        "value": 37
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T18:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T19:00:00Z",
        "value": 33
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T19:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T20:00:00Z",
        "value": 150
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T20:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T21:00:00Z",
        "value": 170
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T21:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T22:00:00Z",
        "value": 130
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T22:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T23:00:00Z",
        "value": 200
      },
      {
        "start_time": "2021-07-10T23:00:00Z",
        "end_time": "2021-07-10T24:00:00Z",
        "value": 55
      }
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "line", "point": true},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "start_time",
      "bin": {"binned": true},
      "scale": {"padding": "-8"},
      "type": "temporal",
      "title": "Time"
    },
    "x2": {"field": "end_time"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Count"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 ways to do so as far as I know:

1. [Band](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/band.html) : Adding `bandPosition` in `x` encoding (easier as designed)
   [See Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQSBpjYQaALzhpQmAJ44d6AGZ1FIAE5wN2tJksM4SqHMxIasiGhCvZmOH8QAF8leBoyLDQARjEABiUAdxoAE3ofP3dPOEsLFKR3XRBiJEEnb1QAbVAId0tMAH1MGgRjEAAmOPbo-jiAdn5ouIAVOLjUMYm4gC0LQJSmlrbO7t6BodHoqanZpRKy4wBmONCausbm1p8Vnv7BkbitybHdkHnFq-QbtfvR9u2XhZ9k4YmNTiBakh6h9ll1busHv9njM5rIFpdYas7hs4ocASi9qUQahogBOE4KM5Qi5La5wn44vHI17vDF0rEI0YAFnxr2BxminXBkOhbK+9OxDx5zNR6Np4o5vziYl5QKJxj6FKpovlHQlnOVqqUrN130lowAbEbiuq0BatRDzjD2fClVaZca0c6Fa6cX1rfy0IdDsKnWK9Yq-daTZ8I76HgAOAO2kntPqh6neuMMxPRr3hs0G0nJg5oToOkU02OFpXFj1vfOm-W-IYl4nxDM66vNjat+sxzHx4bRJ7jQGE0uoe2dquDnPD0c7WVZmu9pFjgk2yeamcrnsjQV5uXdyMHpkbvkphMVsNN0-D89Lz3Hufm6LSi9qyfk3cF-fDj8nwbF8XXnWI2wFMFKUdTM-3vcD+0bE8h2id1PwnYl2naX87xQtCgIHUC339etAxJH9oMrPd4JI9DgOolCk1IlNDnTSjb2QsCmLowifTAus6LI4McM4t8BIIpDX05ToIJiDt2Ng3D5xkxCQL481ulkkkdwUrspN+TTVIY5T1yAsjomOET9I2LCj2MjTH3HLdMKg7VZyI6THM3Xjsw0wCnLIsQxGCABdUIQGQSwAGsigMIwfGEWQdCUHA2E8TB7EcOBwsCVwUk8MgigADyKMw4EEFIfCotklCYTwijq2Qksq1AHCccLoFKYxQBSNhkHqqpfINDcgNXEZ2i82YwqUOK2gCBBUssUoLGaTBBDaYZaVqpA0QABXUOh2HkCZwqK9pSpocqWvotlwv0C6rp8QMZsMNoAEcGB21aChoUgVrodafAAYTYBggmCCGgA)

```
  "x": {
    ...,
    "bandPosition": 0,
    "scale": { "domain": ["2021-07-10T00:00:00Z", "2021-07-10T23:00:00Z"]},
  },
```

2. [Axis](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html) : Adding `tickOffset` and `labelOffset` in `axis` of `x` encoding (ticks/labels are separated and more controllable in terms of px)
   [See Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQSBpjYQaALzhpQmAJ44d6AGZ1FIAE5wN2tJksM4SqHMxIasiGhCvZmOH8QAF8leBoyLDQARjEABiUAdxoAE3ofP3dPOEsLFKR3XRBiJEEnb1QAbVAId0tMAH1MGgRjEAAmOPbo-jiAdn5ouIAVOLjUMYm4gC0LQJSmlrbO7t6BodHoqanZpRKy4wBmONCausbm1p8Vnv7BkbitybHdkHnFq-QbtfvR9u2XhZ9k4YmNTiBakh6h9ll1busHv9njM5rIFpdYas7hs4ocASi9qUQahogBOE4KM5Qi5La5wn44vHI17vDF0rEI0YAFnxr2BxminXBkOhbK+9OxDx5zNR6Np4o5vziYl5QKJxj6FKpovlHQlnOVqqUrN130lowAbEbiuq0BatRDzjD2fClVaZca0c6Fa6cX1rfy0IdDsKnWK9Yq-daTZ8I76HgAOAO2kntPqh6neuMMxPRr3hs0G0nJg5oToOkU02OFpXFj1vfOm-W-IYl4nxDM66vNjat+sxzHx4bRJ7jQGE0uoe2dquDnPD0c7WVZmu9pFjgk2yeamcrnsjQV5uXdyMHpkbvkphMVsNN0-D89Lz3Hufm6LSi9qyfk3cF-fDj8nwbF8XXnWI2wFMFKUdTM-3vcD+0bE8h2id1PwnYl2naX87xQtCgIHUC339etAxJH9oMrPd4JI9DgOolCk1IlNDnTSjb2QsCmLowifTAus6LI4McM4t8BIIpDX05ToIJiDt2Ng3D5xkxCQL481ulkkkdwUrspN+TTVIY5T1yAsjomOET9I2LCj2MjTH3HLdMKg7VZyI6THM3Xjsw0wCnLIsQxGCABdUIQGQSwAGsigMIwfGEWQdCUHA2E8TB7EcOBwsCVwUk8MgigADyKMw4EEFIfCotklCYTwijq2Qksq1AHCccK4raAIEFSyxSgsZpMEENphlpJQkCKmgKj0GgoCigB5EwTAgOAMpJBIQEEJAmHKxbltW0FgnCor2lKmhypa+i2XC-QzounxAyUTqfAARwYJB-DoAoaFIAa6GGnwAGE2AYIIjuCIA)

```
  "x": {
    ...,
    "axis": { "tickOffset": 10, "labelOffset": 10 }
  },
```

Comment: It's so close with bandPosition but for bandPosition: 0 it works for the left side but the right side then ends up even further away. And the axis offsets seem to push the tick marks outside the chart.

Comment: Is bandPosition: 1 what you desire then?

Comment: wahab memon's answer below is closer to what I was looking for, but thanks for the info, just getting into Vega-Lite and it all helps!

Comment: @woolyninja Oh, seems I misunderstood your meaning, just add "scale" in "x" encoding for bandPosition method. It should be another way to achieve what you want=)